# Поиск подматрицы c наибольшим количеством нечетных чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Всем добрый вечер. В программе матрица считывается из файла. Суть задания в том, чтобы надо найти непрерывную подматрицу, в которой находится самое большое количество нечетных цифр и на выход выписать:
количество элементов этой подматрицы
координату крайней левой верхней точки этой подматрицы (ряд, столбец)
координату крайней правой нижней точки этой подматрицы(ряд, столбец)

пример:

```
 1  9  2  8  6  1
 8  1 11  7  6  4
10 12  1  9 12 14
 8 10  3  5 17  8
 6  4 10 13 16 19
```

Вывод:

```
6 (количество элементов подматрицы)
1, 2 (крайняя левая верхняя)
3, 3 (крайняя правая нижняя)
```

Может кто подсказать как это реализовать?Заранее спасибо

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Это учебная задача (перебор всех вариантов с целью изучения языка Python) или олимпиадная (оптимизация для больших M*N)?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, это больше похоже на вопрос на интервью от Google ...  Хотя там еще должны были ограничить сложность алгоритма `< O(n^2)` ;-)

Comment: @MaxU, раз уж в комментариях пошло обсуждение, а автор вопроса не вмешивается, то я был бы благодарен за ссылку на решение за O(n^2).

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, прошу прощения, с `O(N^2)` - я слегка погорячился. Вот [ссылки на похожие вопросы](https://www.google.de/search?q=interview+question+find+island+matrix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=y_gXWpSSEYXN8gfVzqT4AQ)

Comment: а что такое матрица ?

Comment: если все элементы подматрицы должны быть нечётными, то с помощью условия `el % 2 == 0` задача сводится к поиску максимальной подматрицы из одних нулей. [Find largest rectangle containing only zeros in an N×N binary matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2478447/4279)